# guzzle http return 504 Gateway Time-out

Tags: php, jquery, http, laravel-5, guzzle

I try to communicate with api and it always return me 504 Gateway Time-out. I try 'get' http request in jQuery in ajax and it works fine. Here is my code:

```
$.ajax({
    type:'GET',
    url: 'http://example.com',
    success:function(data){
        console.log(data);
    }
});
```

However, the problem is when I use to call this 'get' http request from php by guzzle. I try something like this:

```
$this->client = new Client();

$result = $this->client->request('GET', 'http://example.com');

return $result->getStatusCode();
```

This doesn't work.It always return me 504 Gateway Time-out. Do you know what wrong happened?
When i type url for example 'http://google.com' instead of 'http://example.com it works fine by jQuery and also by Guzzle php.

Comment: Check webserver/php logfiles.

Comment: I am not sure where to find these files. I have Debian and I am newbie in Linux environment.

Comment: @Matej Did you managed to solve this issue? I'm still having this same problem. Read somewhere that this might be related to PHP FPM. Although, I tried updating it but still can't get this to work.